# Apache Mod_Rewrite Help

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to convert a subdirectory to a variable for use in a query.

e.g.

domain/subdir/**STRING** (Need the "**STRING**" subdir)

converted to:

domain/subdir/index.php?q=STRING

All I'm getting are Internal Server Errors and 404's and the phpinfo() for some odd reason.

P.S.

Tried the info on this page already: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

EDIT:

This appears to be working.
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?qst=$1

But it limits the match to AlphaNum characters and I would like to inlcude, -, _ and the # if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/index\.php(.*) - [L]
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ /subdir/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: this rule assumes that any request to domain/subdir/STRING with be served from domain/subdir/index.php?q=STRING.  You have to ensure that there is index.php in domain/subdir/ directory. Also check apache error log to see what resource it tries to get.

Comment: index.php is in the subdir.
[Wed Jun 08 16:31:28 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/subdir/string

Comment: hmm its still accessing domain/subdir/string so rewrite rule is not applied. do you have RewriteEngine On  and RewriteBase set ?

Comment: This is how the .htaccess in the subdir folder
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*) ^subdir/index.php?qst=$1 [L]

Comment: i have edited answer. and verifed on my test machine. Try again and make sure you restart your server as well

Comment: Gosh... Ok i dint copy the above line first.. that is necessary to stop loop. Now copy exactly as it is.

Comment: Nothin again. 404. Rewrite is working because I've tested something simple like turning the subdir/index.htm into subdir/index.php

Comment: and can you post the rule that you wrote for that ?

Comment: `Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]`

Comment: hmm one thing i am not using \ before . in my first first , i edited it now . last comment, put NC as well in rules and give it go and if not working then i am out of ideas :)

Comment: Nothing again... well thanks for trying anyway. I'm looking for a manual for that module now. Can you think of any configuration rules that I might have wrong in the httpd.conf? I've already tried and commented with # some <Directory /> parameters to see if anything helped but even with all off nothing happens. It rewrites simple .htm to .php but nothing with the subdir as a string.

Comment: Hi there, can you read my "EDIT" part on the original question and help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ /subdir/index.php?q=$1
```

The `RewriteCond` checks if the requested document isn't an existing file, that way we don't get a recursive call for index.php

The next rule is a common rewrite to request `/subdir/index.php`.

Comment: I'm sorry this didn't work either. I might have problems with the server configuration. I've tested the rewrite with something simple like turning the subdir/index.htm into subdir/index.php and that worked. I don't know why this doesn't.